# My name includes space - How do I enter my username when typing command?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

My username in Minecraft is `sun solar arrow`. This name includes spaces.

**Situation** - When I want to get OP privilege, a user who has OP privilege will enter:

```
/op sun solar arrow
```

But my username includes spaces. So it shows an error message:

> Invaild syntax

How do I enter my username?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you surround your name in quotes, the game will read it literally. That means that spaces, brackets, etc will be interpreted as their real characters rather than part of the syntax of the command.

For instance:

```
/op "sun solar arrow"
/tp "angussidney" ~ ~10 ~
```

Answer (score 2):

From the server console you can do: `op @p[name="solar arrow"]`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, is there a question for this? ;P

Comment: I made one ^_^ gosh-darn my lack of Reputation over here! :o

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/386120/how-do-i-op-a-user-who-has-spaces-in-their-username-on-a-minecraft-server