# when doing testfor my name has a space in it so it doesnt work

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

when i type up testfor in the command block then put my username it doesn't register MORR15 (my username is SMASHER MORR15) what do i need to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My name includes space - How do I enter my username when typing command?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/303358/my-name-includes-space-how-do-i-enter-my-username-when-typing-command)

Answer (score 0):

You can use your [UUID](https://minecraft.wiki/w/UUID) instead.

> UUIDs (Universally Unique IDentifiers) are 128 bit long numbers which are used by Minecraft to distinguish between separate instances.

They have tools like [this one](https://mcuuid.net/) that you can use to convert your Username into a UUID

Comment: Are you sure that tool works for Bedrock Edition users?